# Nodemailer send email after certain date?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, nodemailer

I am creating a node.js, mongoose, express, and mongodb web app. I am new to coding but I would like to use nodemailer to send emails to users. Specifically, I would like to code a form that a user can enter in their email + days that are important to them. I would like  to  use nodemailer to automatically send them an email a week before the dates they entered reminding them of the date each year. How should I approach this using javascript? I really don't know where to begin. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just to give one possible approach: I would use CRON jobs to implement this scenario, in the case of NodeJS this means using a module like [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron). The service could be realized as a RESTful API.

The concrete implementation **depends** on performance claims and properties like amount of running reminders but one very basic solution would be to store the dates inside of MongoDB and reload it on every web application restart. You have then to create a CRON job for every date. **Be aware: This strategy could lead to performance issues!**

Here you find a simple pseudo code for creating a CRON job based on a date stored in database:

```
const cron = require('cron');

let date = new Date(...); // Date object fetched from database
let job = new cron.CronJob(date, () => {

    // Send email with nodemailer
});

job.start();
```